# как поставить картинку на ярлык с помощью python

Tags: python, icon, python-3.9

Можно ли как то добавить картинку (пиктограму\иконку) к ярлыку на рабочем столе на windows с помощью python? (у меня есть ярлык и я хочу с помощью питона поставить ему картинку), заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какую иконку, где поменять? больше информации дайте

Comment: поставить на ярлык картинку с помощью python

Comment: на рабочем столе windows, на Ubuntu, может быть в Web GUI, может еще где то? столько вариантов, столько возможных решений

Comment: на рабочем столе виндовс

Comment: "Хочу иконку! Несмотря на Советскую власть! И чтоб окна, открывались и закрывались Мышью!"